# multiple functions and extract list in ocaml

Tags: function, ocaml

about multiple functions, I want to have the result like f(f(f(x)))
this is my code

```
let rec multifun (f:'a -> 'a) (n:int) = match n with
|1 -> fun (x:'a) -> f x
|_ -> multifun(fun (x:'a) -> f(f x)) (n-1);;
```

but the result (multifun (fn x => x * x) 3) 2 returns 65536 instead of 256,
I know the reason but I don't know how to edit it, actually I should initiate a function g and change it, instead of keeping change f itself, but I don't know how to do it in this code

another one is about achieving this function: ltake [3; 7; 5; 1; 2] 3 returns [3; 7; 5].

my code is

```
let rec ltake l n = match (l,n) with
|([],n) -> []
|(hd::tl,0) -> []
|(hd::tl,n) -> hd::(ltake tl n-1);;
```

but the compiler said that "This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type int"
still don't know why.  hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, then you’re trying to implement [apply_n_times](https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel/blob/master/lib/fn.ml#L30) function.

For the second problem, you've forgotten parens around `n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Like ivg said, your second problem is about missing parens around `n-1` in your last line.

For your first problem, it comes indeed from the fact that each recursive call doubles the number of nested `f` instead of adding one.

You need to add f out of the `multiline` function:

```
let rec multifun (f:'a -> 'a) (n:int) = match n with
| 0 -> fun x -> x (* I added the 0 case as it can be quite usefull *)
| _ -> f (multifun f) (n-1);;
```

You can also try more simply to write multifun once the x is obtained:

```
let rec multifun f n x =
  if n = 0
  then x
  else multifun f (n-1) (f x);;
```

This works the same (and is probably more efficient) and you are totally allowed to type `let g = multifun f 10`.

Note that good practice would require you to add a `assert (n>=0)` somewhere (as that's the kind of assertion you really want to be true :-p).